# How can I display a series of colors chosen for a gradient in Qt?

Tags: qt, colors, gradient

I want to make a QDialog box (I don't think there is one in the library...sigh) that allows the user to select any number of colors to add to a gradient (and possibly adjust them), sort of like the Gradient option that you can use to recolor objects in Power Point.

Is there an easy way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried similar concept to change QDialog Background Color as per user choiceis. I used Style Sheet through my code. Here's a sample piece of my code.

```
void Dialog::changeBackgroundColor()
{
    int bg_r = ui->horizontalSlider_2->value(); // user set value on horizontal slider
    int bg_g = ui->horizontalSlider_3->value(); // user set value on horizontal slider
    int bg_b = ui->horizontalSlider_4->value(); // user set value on horizontal slider

    ui->R_label->setText(QString::number(bg_r));
    ui->G_label->setText(QString::number(bg_g));
    ui->B_label->setText(QString::number(bg_b));

    QString styleSheet = "QDialog { background-color : rgb(%1, %2, %3)}";

    this->setStyleSheet(styleSheet.arg(bg_r).arg(bg_g).arg(bg_b));

   //in your case for gradient you can use
   QString styleSheet = "QDialog { qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0.568, stop:0 rgba(%1, %2, %3, 255)) }";

   this->setStyleSheet(styleSheet.arg(bg_r).arg(bg_g).arg(bg_b));

}
```

I hope you can use this concept for your purpose.